# Object with key assigned to a function returning undefined but console.log shows the data

Tags: javascript, callback, undefined

I have the following which is running thru a loop going over the response from a returned JSON result.

I am able to push all of this data into my object product.variations with no problems. The **product.variations.quantity** however will not return the string data from the function that I have associated. The function that is attached **getProductStock** is called ok but it comes in as **undefined** when I attempt to return the data back into the key that will be pushed.

The reason I am confused is because when I run a console.log callback function I can see the string data appearing with no problem.

The issue is that it will not return into the quantity key and then push back into my main object **product**. Keeps returning undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciate :)

```
   product.variations.push({
               'identifier' :  dataJSON.msg[z].sku,
               'size' : dataJSON.msg[z].size,
               'quantity' : getProductStock(token, dataJSON.msg[z].sku, function(stockLevel){
                 console.log(stockLevel);
                 return stockLevel;
               })
             });
```

Then later on I have the function that is getting called 'getProductStock'

```
function getProductStock(token, goods_sn, callback){
  var post_data = "token=" + token + "&goods_sn=" + goods_sn;
  var api_url = 'https://randomapiurl.com/getStock?';

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: api_url,
    data: post_data
  };

  curl.request(options, function(err,data){
    var JSON_result = JSON.parse(data);
        JSON_result.msg.page_result.forEach(function(data, index){
          callback(data.goods_number);
        });
  });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

```js
     
function getProductStock(token, goods_sn, callback){
  var post_data = "token=" + token + "&goods_sn=" + goods_sn;
  var api_url = 'https://randomapiurl.com/getStock?';

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: api_url,
    data: post_data
  };

  curl.request(options, function(err,data){
    var JSON_result = JSON.parse(data);
        JSON_result.msg.page_result.forEach(function(data, index){
          pushData(data.goods_number);
        });
  });

}
function pushData(quantity)
{

  product.variations.push({
               'identifier' :  dataJSON.msg[z].sku,
               'size' : dataJSON.msg[z].size,
               'quantity' : quantity
           });
           
 }
```